# SQL Query on selecting rows only if its available in other table for a particular section

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query. I want to select all the records from table 1, with one condition.
If a Type is 'Prime' in Table 1, and that Semi+Prime combination exist in Table 2, only then we will select it from table 1.
For example, in this sample attached  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkvO2.png), 4 and 6 (having type=prime) are there in table 2, so we consider it for output. 8( having type=prime) does not exist in table 2, so we dont take it in output.
This condition will be applicable only when Type is Prime in table1.

I have created the table here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13a5a2a6be51804a89ff5fd47edeeb70

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Exists` to get what you want.

```
create table t2 
(Semi integer(10),
Type varchar(10)
);
create table t1
(Group2 varchar(10),
Semi int,
Type varchar(10)
);

insert into t2
VALUES(17,'PRIME'),
(4,'PRIME'),
(2,'PRIME'),
(3,'PRIME'),
(43,'PRIME'),
(34,'PRIME'),
(6,'PRIME'),
(23,'PRIME')

insert into t1
VALUES('A',1,'X'),
('A',2,'Y'),
('A',3,'Z'),
('A',4,'PRIME'),
('A',5,'X'),
('A',6,'PRIME'),
('A',7,'X'),
('A',8,'PRIME')
```

Query:

```
select * from t1
where type <>'PRIME'
or EXISTS
          (
             SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.Semi=t1.Semi and t2.Type=t1.Type and t1.Type='PRIME'
          )
```

Output:

| Group2 | Semi | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | X |
| A | 2 | Y |
| A | 3 | Z |
| A | 4 | PRIME |
| A | 5 | X |
| A | 6 | PRIME |
| A | 7 | X |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c2940045893e2f82a29101dd0e05d20)*

Comment: This will give us only the ones with PRime in Table 1. But we want rest records as well from the Table 1 which are not prime. Please refer to the sample input/output attached

Comment: @Ayn76 sorry, my mistake. I have revised my answer. And thanks a lot for providing db-fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out below query it may help you:(Try it in your fiddle only)
First do the left join and using case condition remove non-prime:

```
select Group2,Type2,Group3 from t1 left join t2 on t1.type2=t2.group1 where (case when t1.group3 = 'PRIME' then t1.group3=t2.type1 else 1=1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

select t1.Group1,t2.Semi,t1.Type from t1,t2 where t1.Type='PRIME' and t1.Semi=t2.Semi and t1.Type=t2.Type;

table t1:

[image]

table t2:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: This will give us only the ones with PRime in Table 1. But we want rest records as well from the Table 1 which are not prime. Please refer to the sample input/output attached